# how can i create css for the lable which i need to print on the 8.5 by 11 size page?

Tags: asp.net, css

How can i create css for this sort of requirement?

Dimensions for Custom Label Fields:

```
Top Margin: 0”
Side Margin: 0” 
Vertical Pitch: 3”
Horizontal Pitch: 4”
Page Size: 8.5 x 11

Label Height: 3”
Label Width: 4” 
Number Across: 2
Number Down: 3

PAGE Top Margin: 2” 
PAGE Side Margin: .5”
```

This creates the backwards L shape that allows our margins for perforation.

Below is the code for which i want top adjust the above setting

```
<div>
   <%#Eval("FirstName")%> <%#Eval("LastName")%> <br />
   <%#Eval("RoleName")%><br />
   <%#Eval("School")%><br />
   <asp:Image ID="Image8"  Width="190" Visible='<%# Eval("ProgWellness")%>' runat="server" ToolTip="Member of the Wellness Advisory Council" ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/ThirdI.EventBooking/images/dnnp_Advisory.png" />
   <br />
   <asp:Image ID="Image9" Visible='<%# Eval("ProgEssMax")%>' runat="server" ToolTip="Certified in Maximized Mind"  ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/ThirdI.EventBooking/images/dnnp_MaxMind.png" />
   <asp:Image ID="Image10" Visible='<%# Eval("ProgEssNerve")%>' runat="server" ToolTip="Certified in Maximized Nerve Supply" ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/ThirdI.EventBooking/images/dnnp_NerveSupply.png" />
   <asp:Image ID="Image11" Visible='<%# Eval("ProgEssWellness")%>' runat="server" ToolTip="Certified in Maximized Nutrition" ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/ThirdI.EventBooking/images/dnnp_Nutrition.png" />
   <asp:Image ID="Image12" Visible='<%# Eval("ProgEssOxygen")%>' runat="server" ToolTip="Certified in Maximized Oxygen and Lean Muscle" ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/ThirdI.EventBooking/images/dnnp_Excercise.png" />
   <asp:Image ID="Image13" Visible='<%# Eval("ProgEssBodyToxin")%>' runat="server" ToolTip="Certified in Minimized Toxins"  ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/ThirdI.EventBooking/images/dnnp_Toxicity.png" />
   <asp:Image ID="Image14" Visible='<%# Eval("ProgMLHealthCenter")%>' runat="server" ToolTip="Certified in Minimized Toxins" ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/ThirdI.EventBooking/images/dnnp_HealthCenter.png" />
</div>
```

i want to take print out for my above code to a page size of 8.5 by 11, with the the dimension given, how can i make setting for that?
Also, i want 6 labels of mentioned size on the 8.5 by 11 size page.

Comment: i want to take print out for my above code to a page size of 8.5 by 11, with the the dimension given, how can i make setting for that?

Answer (score 1):

Well basically CSS supports this. You can use inches as measurements (`width: 4in`) and allows setting the margins of the page (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html). However the support latter in browsers is not quite wide spread. Firefox/Mozilla for example doesn't, IE of since IE8, etc. So you'll need to test this.

So in your case you'll probably start with something like this:

```
@page {
  margin-top: 2in;
  margin-left: .5in;
}

div {
  width: 4in;
  height: 3in;
}
```

Otherwise it's no different than any other CSS.

Comment: solution u suggested, i knew already. but that don't work out. want some alternate solution. Please let me know.

Comment: You'll need to give more details then. What exactly "didn't work out"? Did you use a browser that supports `@page`?

Comment: I did the same as you explained me, but the problem is that i am getting 8 labels on a page, while i want 6 on a page. To adjust that i am in trouble.